# Activation parameter not working in GridSearch

Tags: keras, grid-search

I am trying to make a GridSearch for best parameters, like this:

```
def MultiPerceptron(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_cross_entropy', kernel_initializer = 'random_uniform', activation = 'relu', units = 16):
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(InputLayer(30))
  model.add(Dense(units = units, activation = activation, kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer))
  model.add(Dense(units = units, activation = activation, kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer))
  model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
  model.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = loss, metrics =['binary_accuracy'])
  return model

classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn = MultiPerceptron, validation_split = 0.1, validation_batch_size = 50)
param = {'batch_size': [10, 30],
         'epochs': [50, 100],
         'optimizer': ['adam', 'sgd'],
         'loss': ['binary_crossentropy', 'hinge'],
         'kernel_initializer': ['random_uniform', 'normal'],
         'activation': ['relu', 'tanh'],
         'units': [16, 8]}

search = GridSearchCV(estimator = classifier, param_grid = param, scoring = 'accuracy', cv = 5)
search = search.fit(x,y)
```

And i am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter activation for estimator KerasClassifier.
This issue can likely be resolved by setting this parameter in the KerasClassifier constructor:
`KerasClassifier(activation=relu)`
Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`
```

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @trinity420 Yes, passing the parameter `activation=relu` to `KerasClassifier` solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

- Had the same error yesterday as `keras` does not support "wrappers" anymore.
- And If you are using `scikeras.wrappers`, you will have to define your parameters like

> model following with 2 underscores(_) and then parameter name

```py
# model following with 2 underscores(_) and then parameter name
model__activation=['relu','softmax']
```

For reference, see scikeras official documentation.
https://adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/quickstart.html#grid-search
https://adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/migration.html#default-arguments-in-build-fn-model

```py
params={
    'batch_size':[20,25],
    'epochs':[50,70],
    'model__neurons_1':[6,7],
    'model__neurons_2':[4,3],
    'model__activation':['relu','softmax'],
    'model__optimizer':['adam','rmsprop'],
    'model__dropout':[0.1,0.2]
    }

def create_model(neurons_1,neurons_2,activation,optimizer,dropout):
    nn = tf.keras.Sequential()
    nn.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=11))       
    nn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=neurons_1,
               activation=activation,kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    nn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=dropout))
    nn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=neurons_2,activation=activation))    
    nn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=dropout))
    nn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1,activation='sigmoid'))
    nn.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss='binary_crossentropy',
                   metrics=['accuracy']) 
    return nn

model = KerasClassifier(model=create_model)

gs= GridSearchCV(estimator=model,param_grid=params,scoring='accuracy',cv=10,
                     n_jobs=-1,return_train_score=True,verbose=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use activation and layers in **KerasClassifier** constructor

```
def create_model(layers, activation):
        model= Sequential()
        for i, nodes in enumerate(layers):
            if i==0:
                model.add(Dense(nodes, input_dim=X_train.shape[1]))
                model.add(Activation(activation))
            else:
                model.add(Dense(nodes))
                model.add(Activation(activation))
        model.add(Dense(1))
        
        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model
    
    model= KerasClassifier(model=create_model, verbose=0, activation='relu', layers=20)
```

Then

```
layers=[[20],[40,20], [45, 30, 15]]
activations = ['sigmoid','relu']
param_grid = dict(layers=layers, activation=activations, batch_size=[128, 256], epochs=[30])
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid)

grid_result= grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
[grid_result.best_score_,grid_result.best_params_]
```

Its worked!
Finally got below output:

```
[0.8397500000000001,
 {'activation': 'relu',
  'batch_size': 128,
  'epochs': 30,
  'layers': [45, 30, 15]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

sauron's answer works. it is  adding "model__*" in the parameters, like

```
"model__units":[16,32,64],
"model__activation":["linear","relu"],
"model__learning_rate":[0.001,0.01],
```

like this:

```
parameters={
    "model__units":[16,32,64],
    "model__activation":["linear","relu"],
    "model__learning_rate":[0.001,0.01],
    "epochs":[20,50,100]
}
```

Keras does not support "wrappers" anymore.

1. install with pip "scikeras".
2. Use "from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier" / or KerasRegressor
3. for parameters, like above explained add prefix "model__" (with two underline) every thing you will add, but not for "epochs".
4. the rest is same as old.
5. for bestparams use "bestparams["model__*"]" same as you add to parameters

final sample is:

```
parameters={
    "model__units":[32,64],
    "model__learning_rate":[0.001,0.01],
    "model__hidden_layers":[2,3],
    "model__activation":["linear","relu"],
    "model__dropout_rate":[0.0,0.2],
    "epochs":[50,100]
}
kreg=KerasRegressor(build_fn=set_model,verbose=0)
grid=GridSearchCV(estimator=kreg,param_grid=parameters,cv=3)
gridresult=grid.fit(X_train,y_train)
bp=gridresult.best_params_
bestmodel=set_model(units=bp["model__units"],activation=bp["model__activation"],learning_rate=bp["model__learning_rate"],..)
```

normally I did not add it and it not worked. with saurons's answer, when I added, it work.

thanks for the answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think they changed something, because i could only make it work passing the `activation=relu` parameter to `KerasClassifier`.

Other parameters aren't needed there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The following code ran perfectly when using keras.wrappers

```
def build_model(lambda_parameter):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=X.shape[1], activation='relu', 
    kernel_regularizer=l2(lambda_parameter)))
    model.add(Dense(6, activation='relu', 
    kernel_regularizer=l2(lambda_parameter)))
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu', 
    kernel_regularizer=l2(lambda_parameter)))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics= 
    ['accuracy'])
    return model
seed = 1
np.random.seed(seed)
random.set_seed(seed)
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_model, verbose=0, shuffle=False)
lambda_parameter = [0.01, 0.5, 1]
epochs = [50, 100]
batch_size = [20]
param_grid = dict(lambda_parameter=lambda_parameter, epochs=epochs, 
batch_size=batch_size)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, cv=5)
results_1 = grid_search.fit(X, y)
print(f"Best cross-validation score = {results_1.best_score_}")
print(f"Parameters for best cross-validation score = 
{results_1.best_params_}")
accuracy_means = results_1.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
accuracy_stds = results_1.cv_results_['std_test_score']
parameters = results_1.cv_results_['params']
for p in range(len(parameters)):
    print(f"Accuracy {accuracy_means[p]} for params {accuracy_stds[p]}, 
    {parameters[p]}
```

But after switching to Scikeras, I was always getting the a ValueError:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter lambda_parameter for estimator 
KerasClassifier.
This issue can likely be resolved by setting this parameter in the 
KerasClassifier constructor: KerasClassifier(lambda_parameter=0.01)`
Check the list of available parameters with 
estimator.get_params().keys()`
```

I added lambda_parameter=0.01 to the KerasClassifiet to solve the issue

```
model = KerasClassifier(model=build_model, verbose=0, shuffle=False, 
lambda_parameter=0.01)
```