# Migration from keras.wrappers.sci-learn to scikeras

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, migration

Im not very experienced in programming so I dont really know how to do the migration since there is no much documentation about it, the only thing I found was this web https://adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/migration.html
I also tried to go back to the old keras.wrappers but its not avaliable anymore

Any guidance or help would be appreciated.

Here is my code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV


def create_model(lstm_1,lstm_2,dense):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(lstm_1, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
    model.add(LSTM(lstm_2))
    model.add(Dense(dense, activation='linear'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
    return model

param_grid = param_grid = {
    'lstm_1': [32, 64, 128],
    'lstm_2': [32, 64, 128],
    'dense': [16, 32, 64]
}



tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5)

class TwoLayerFeedForward:
     def __call__():
         clf = Sequential()
         clf.add(Dense(9, activation='relu', input_dim=3))
         clf.add(Dense(9, activation='relu'))
         clf.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
         clf.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=SGD())
         return clf



grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, cv=tscv, n_jobs=-1)
grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)


print("The Best parameters: ", grid_result.best_params_)

best_model = grid_result.best_estimator_.model


NN_predictions = best_model.predict(X_test)

NN_mse = np.mean((y_test - NN_predictions.flatten()) ** 2)
NN_rmse = np.sqrt(NN_mse)
print("The Root Mean Squared Error for the Neural Network model is: ", NN_rmse)


NN_r_squared = r2_score(y_test, NN_predictions)

n = len(y_test)
p = 8
NN_adjusted_r_squared = 1 - (1 - NN_r_squared) * (n - 1) / (n - p - 1)

print('The OOS R-squared is: ', NN_r_squared)
print('The OOS Adjusted R-squared is: ', NN_adjusted_r_squared)


plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(y_test, label='Implied Volatility')
plt.plot(NN_predictions, label='NN Forecast')
plt.xlabel('Date Index')
plt.ylabel('Implied Volatility')
plt.title('Actual vs Predicted values')
plt.legend()
plt.show()



from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import L2


LSTM1 = grid_result.best_params_['lstm_1']
LSTM2 = grid_result.best_params_['lstm_2']
DENSE = grid_result.best_params_['dense']


model_REG = Sequential([
    LSTM(LSTM1, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]), return_sequences=True, kernel_regularizer= L2(0.001)),
    LSTM(LSTM2),
    Dense(DENSE, activation = 'linear'),
    Dense(K, activation = 'linear')
])


model_REG.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')


history_REG = model_REG.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=N_epochs, batch_size=N_batch_size, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))


NN_REG_predictions = model_REG.predict(X_test)


NN_REG_mse = np.mean((y_test - NN_REG_predictions.flatten()) ** 2)
NN_REG_rmse = np.sqrt(NN_REG_mse)
print("The Root Mean Squared Error for the Neural Network model is: ", NN_REG_rmse)

NN_r_squared = r2_score(y_test, NN_REG_predictions)

n = len(y_test)
p = 8
NN_adjusted_r_squared = 1 - (1 - NN_r_squared) * (n - 1) / (n - p - 1)

print('The OOS R-squared is: ', NN_r_squared)
print('The OOS Adjusted R-squared is: ', NN_adjusted_r_squared)


plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(y_test, label='Implied Volatility')
plt.plot(NN_REG_predictions, label='NN Forecast')
plt.xlabel('Date Index')
plt.ylabel('Implied Volatility')
plt.title('Actual vs Predicted values')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

`

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77251441  there is an answer. migration from keras to scikeras, generally is the same methods. however there are some differences. maybe the link contains your answers.

Comment: Please consider, solving the OP question instead of providing a link to another answer based on another question. If you want to give hints and links, do it in the comment section. Since commenting is awarded at 50 reputations, you are left with answering **the** question.